# Layout error of xaml file

Tags: java, c#, android, visual-studio

I am using Visual studio 2015, and I am working on Android development in C#. I also use xamarin and xamarin Android player in visual studio. Every thing is working fine. But when I loads Xaml file for watching layout so it does not loads.
[Snapshot of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOBrd.png)

Comment: Is your Xaml file well-formed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried to repair it through the installation package but it was not fixed. It seems that Xamarin for Visual Studio is not stable yet.

But I found a workaround: it's fixed temporary when string file has been changed.

You can also try to run VS as administrator if your issue is related to access authority to the resource folder.